# Which should be used: "wear" or "dress in"?

Tags: word-choice

> 1. The ethnic groups wear colourful traditional costumes.
> 2. The ethnic groups dress in colourful traditional costumes.

In the sentences, which word should be used, wear or dress in? Or are they interchangeable?

Comment: You can also say "dress up in" or "get dressed up in" if the garb is worn for a special occasion or ceremony.

Comment: dress up is not the same thing at all. In the two examples given, dress in and wear mean the same thing and are both correct and formal.

Comment: @Lambie: Read the whole statement. There's an *if*-clause.

Comment: Why confuse the issue? Also, traditional costumes here may not be a way of dressing up at all. I consider that a separate issue.

Answer (score 1):

They can mean the same thing. Since *dress* is intransitive in this instance, the preposition *in* functions to tell us *how* they dress or *what* they wear. So we understand in either case the ethnic groups wear *colorful traditional costumes*.

The problem is *dress* can have a slightly different meaning than *wear* in the following sense:

> [dress](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dress)
>
> 1. **b** :  to put on or wear formal, elaborate, or fancy clothes

So, sentence 2 can imply that these costumes are worn during formal occasions, whereas sentence 1 does not.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first one, "wear", is probably what you want most of the time. It sounds natural and idiomatic.

The second sentence only sounds ok if you're describing a specific event, as opposed to the general situation.